# Go through a text file. Count the emails sent by each distinct email address and print the email address along with the count of emails

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, file

The task is to also print the email address that sent max emails along with the email count and email address that sent min emails with email count.

```
file1 = open("mbox-short.txt")
daywise_mail_count = dict()
for line in file1:
  words= line.split()
  if len(words) == 0 or words[0] !='From': continue
  word = words[1]
  if word not in daywise_mail_count:
    daywise_mail_count[word]= 1
  else:
    daywise_mail_count[word] += 1
print (daywise_mail_count)
Keymax = max(zip(daywise_mail_count.values(), daywise_mail_count.keys()))
print (keymax)
```

Tried above code and got following output:
{'stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za': 2, 'louis@media.berkeley.edu': 3, 'zqian@umich.edu': 4, 'rjlowe@iupui.edu': 2, 'cwen@iupui.edu': 5, 'gsilver@umich.edu': 3, 'wagnermr@iupui.edu': 1, 'antranig@caret.cam.ac.uk': 1, 'gopal.ramasammycook@gmail.com': 1, 'david.horwitz@uct.ac.za': 4, 'ray@media.berkeley.edu': 1}
5

The last output should be like
Maximum emails were sent by: 'cwen@iupui.edu': 5
Minimum emails were sent by: 'antranig@caret.cam.ac.uk': 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your dictionary in `daywise_mail_count` (as you stated in your question) then you can do:

```py
# your dictionary from the question:
daywise_mail_count = {
    "stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za": 2,
    "louis@media.berkeley.edu": 3,
    "zqian@umich.edu": 4,
    "rjlowe@iupui.edu": 2,
    "cwen@iupui.edu": 5,
    "gsilver@umich.edu": 3,
    "wagnermr@iupui.edu": 1,
    "antranig@caret.cam.ac.uk": 1,
    "gopal.ramasammycook@gmail.com": 1,
    "david.horwitz@uct.ac.za": 4,
    "ray@media.berkeley.edu": 1,
}

mx_email, mx_count = max(daywise_mail_count.items(), key=lambda k: k[1])
mn_email, mn_count = min(daywise_mail_count.items(), key=lambda k: k[1])

print(f"Maximum emails were sent by: {mx_email} {mx_count}")
print(f"Minimum emails were sent by: {mn_email} {mn_count}")
```

Prints:

```
Maximum emails were sent by: cwen@iupui.edu 5
Minimum emails were sent by: wagnermr@iupui.edu 1
```